# Can I use my FAA Private Pilot (Foreign Based) without a valid EASA SEPL to fly in USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, ppl

Can I fly in the US using my FAA Private Pilot (Foreign Based) based on my EASA PPL without having renewed SEP(L) - it's EASA's class rating for single piston engine airplanes. By flying I mean using my FAA ASEL rating.

Comment: This question has already been answered.  The answer is NO.

Comment: The answer is YES - read carefully proposed post and letters mentioned in the answer - "The FAA views aircraft ratings as privileges for operating certiain aircraft." - from Grossman letter